# vuetify & v-virtual-scroll : how can I programmatically scroll an item into view?

Tags: vue.js, scroll, vuetify.js

I know what my item height is and I know the position of the item in the list, so I should be able to calculate the scroll position. However, I am not sure how to set the scroll position.

Answer (score 2):

With Vuetify 2 you can use `this.$vuetify.goTo($target, $options)`  where $target is html element query e.g. '#targetElementId' or HTMLElement object, while all available $options you can find [here](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/vuetify/#functions-goTo).

In Vuetify 3, you can use [`scrollToIndex()`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-virtual-scroll/#exposed-scrollToIndex).

Answer (score 1):

For v-virtual-scroll, you can set the scrollTop to scroll an item into view.

You can assign an id to your v-virtual-scroll element for easy selection, then set the scrollTop, like this:

```
let itemHeight = 48, itemIndex = 10; // set as appropriate
document.getElementById("my-scroller").scrollTop = itemHeight * itemIndex;
```

Comment: The programatic scrolling behaviour for Vuetify 3 is documented here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/scrolling/